# Ubuntu 12.04 not prompting me to 14.04.1

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04.
I know that 14.04.1 has been released and i can update from the freakin update mananger.
BUT
It aint showing me the prompt to upgrade.
Only shows me that new hardware support is abvilebale.
Can anybody say whats the problem.
PS:Its been over 48 hours since release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the update, try running `update-manager` from terminal.

If not, then kill that (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) if it isn't doing anything, and run `update-manager -d`.

For me, that gives me 14.10, but I am on 14.04, so it may show 14.04.1 for you, on 12.04.

Finally, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` may update it, but I'm not sure it does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15980/discussion-between-tim-and-t01vo).

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` from the command line, in the past I have not had luck upgrading through software manager but it has gone smoothly through the command line

Comment: I've heard that theres an huge possibility for it to crash on installiation or after installiation if u do it through the command line

Comment: There is just as much chance (if not more) of it crashing if you do it through the GUI. Command line is typically safer.

Comment: Never had it crash when using the command line - wherever you heard that is either very out of date, horribly mis-informed or deliberately spreading FUD

Comment: the terminal is what the gui uses, but more reliable as it is not susceptible to errors in the gui itself, all the gui runs is that command with a few variables for what you choose to install or not